# Problemas con una query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo unos problemas con una Query que no consigo sacar, la estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

**child**

```
  child_id ----->CLAVE PRIMARIA
  child_name 
  birth_date 
  gender 
  address 
  city
```

**letter**

```
  letter_id --->Clave primaria
  child_id ---->Clave ajena que referencia a la tabla child,child_id
  arrival_date 
  number_toys
```

**wished_toy**

```
  letter_id -->Clave primaria a su vez clave ajena con letter_id de letter
  toy_id ---->Clave primaria a su ves clave ajena con toy_id de toy
```

**toy**

```
toy_id--->Clave primaria 
toy_name 
price 
toy_type
manufacturer
```

Bien en la query se me pide que obtenga las cartas recibidas donde se hayan pedido al menos 3 juguetes con precio inferior a 10 euros,se pide el id_letter,child_name,birth_date y numero de juguetes pedidos en la carta number_toys

Bien,la primera parte de la query la tengo clara,primero saco las cartas de los niños que han pedido al menos 3 jueguetes y lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
select l.letter_id,l.number_toys,h.child_name,h.birth_date
from letter l natural join child h
where l.number_toys >='3';
```

Bien, no se como seguir con esta query, como relacionar con mas joins para llegar a la tabla toy que es donde se guarda el precio de los juguetes y decirle que el precio debe ser inferior a 10.

Comment: Sugerencia aparte... nunca uses natural joins. Te va a jugar mal partido, sino hoy, mañana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es un join a `wished_toy` y `toy` que limita a solo los juguetes que cuestan menos de 10 euros.

Luego agrupas por cartas y usas la cláusula `having count(*) >= 3` para limitar el resultado a los que incluyen 3 o más juguetes que satisfacen el filtro descrito arriba.

```
select l.letter_id,
       c.child_name,
       c.birth_date,
       l.number_toys
  from letter l
  join child c
    on c.child_id = l.child_id
  join wished_toy wt
    on wt.letter_id = l.letter_id
  join toy t
    on t.toy_id = wt.toy_id
   and price < 10
 group by l.letter_id, 
          c.child_name,
          c.birth_date,
          l.number_toys
 having count(*) >= 3
```